# How to configure IIS inside Windows Container on AKS

Tags: kubernetes, iis, containers, .net-4.8, windows-container

I'm using the .NET Framework (I can't use .NET Core) for a solution that needs to stay alive the entire time it's running.

Normally I would configure IIS and keep it active all the time but inside the container I am not able to perform these settings.

Is there a "correct" way to configure IIS?

.NET Framework 4.8
Kubernetes
Windows Container

Answer (score 0):

To manage IIS in a container, most professionals (server administrators) use PowerShell.

If you prefer IIS Manager, then you will have to prepare the container and enable IIS remote management. I have a very basic example in my blog post, https://blog.lextudio.com/remote-management-of-containerized-iis-instances-on-windows-server-core-f6864c74917f